# Cannot Update the system : E:Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, apt, upgrade

This is my problem

I was changing ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10. All the downloads and installations were OK. Then after the restart, my touchpad and my wireless card were unable to use.

I could solve the problem which was with the touchpad.

I was thinking that the problem with the wireless will able to solve with upgrade, and update commands. So I opened the terminal and entered the commands. But I cannot update the system. I tried several times but not succeeded.

This is what the details said about my problem :

```
E:Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
```